# Why is Request.Form["myfield"] empty unless property is available?

Tags: c#, razor-pages, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

In a RazorPage, I submit a form but in the model `OnPost()`, Request.Form["myfield"] is empty.

```
<form method="post">
<input id="myfield"/>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

But if I add a class level property in the model:

```
public string myfield { get; set; }
```

and update the form to use a TagHelper:

```
<form method="post">
<input asp-for="myfield"/>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

`Request.Form["myfield"]` is populated when it hits the breakpoint in OnPost(). But the actual property is null in `OnPost()`.

Does anyone understand what is going on? Meaning:

Why doesn't `Request.Form["myfield"]` populate with the class level property?

Why doesn't the property populate?

-- EDIT --
The first part of this because I'm using `id` instead of `name`.

Still not sure about the 2nd part on the `asp-for` and model property.

Comment: `asp-for` also sets the `name` attribute - Have you tried setting that in your first code snippet?

Comment: Can you provide a code snippet of what that looks like? There is no asp-name attribute.

Comment: I just mean try `<input id="myfield" name="myfield" />` without the `asp-for` (your first code example). I feel like it goes off `name` rather than `id`.

Comment: You are right. It is name. that solves one problem. Do you have any idea about the asp-for and property question? I updated the OP.

Comment: Try adding the `BindProperty` attribute, i.e. `[BindProperty] public string myfield { get; set; }`. This might only work for classes, rather than simple strings. Let me know if that's the case and I can post an answer to explain how that would work.

Comment: Yes - BindProperty does work. I had actually tried it earlier and the property was null. I don't know what I did wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Razor pages are not like Web Forms where those Form fields are automatically populated. They are more like a simplified MVC controller.

You can specify that the all of the form fields are passed in by adding it as a parameter to your post method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(IFormCollection data) {
   var myField = data["myField"];
   ...
}
```

Using Bindable properties is the preferred way to persist data between the client and server.